# Error using mlogit for simulated data for choice discrete

Tags: r, multiple-choice

I am trying to simulate data and adjust the model for choice-based conjoint analysis (mlogit). However, I am getting the error (Error in solve.default (H, g [! Fixed])). I believe it is because sometimes I have more than one choice for the same respondent, but I understand that this is one of the possibilities of this model and so I could not find a solution, someone who has worked with discrete choice and used the mlogit package can help me? Below is my code:

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")
library(dplyr)
library(conjoint)
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000
#- create dummy data
data = expand.grid(Cor = c("black", "white"),
                   Brand = c("X", "Y"),
                   Price = c("low", "high"))
levn <- rbind("black", "white","X", "Y", "low", "high")
data$trat <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
UA <- 7
UB <- 6.5
UC <- 6
UD <- 5.5
UE <- 5
UF <- 4.5
UG <- 4
UH <- 3.5
data$utility <- c(UA, UB, UC, UD, UE, UF, UG, UH)
data <- bind_rows(replicate(n, data, simplify = FALSE))
erro <- rnorm(n)
data$erro <- erro
data$determinist <- floor(rowSums(data[,5:6]))
data$id <- rep(1:n, each = 8)
data <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(determinist = (determinist == max(determinist)))
data$choice <- ifelse(data$determinist=="TRUE",1,0)
library(mlogit)
cbc.mlogit <- mlogit.data(data=data, choice="choice", shape="long", varying=1:3, alt.levels=paste("pos", 1:8), id.var="id")
cbc.ml <- mlogit(choice ~ 0 + Cor + Brand + Price, data = cbc.mlogit)
```

Using the `nnet package` I got a solution, however, I don't think it's correct, because in the choice-based joint analysis the intercept is zero.

```
library("nnet")
model <- multinom(choice ~ Cor + Brand + Price, data = cbc.mlogit)
summary(model)
```

Already researched other posts and could not solve, any help is welcome!

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. In my env your cord runs. Are packages the newest version ?

Comment: Yes, R and packages are newer versions. Strange, because I really can't reproduce the code.